# Next js Dynamic Router misfiring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The following is my folder structure in next js

```
/pages
|_/index.js
|_/programs
   |_/[program_id].js
   |_/index.js
```

Both pages have `getStaticProps` which make a fetch api to pass `props` to the page;
Also `/[program_id].js` has a `getStaticPaths` which provides 3 paths,

###### Question:

When i load `https://www.domain/programs` it renders. `/programs/index.js`, from there i click `<Link href="/programs/P01">` it renders `/programs/[program_id].js` page;

**But from there when i click `<Link href="/programs">`, it fires `getStaticProps` of `/programs/index.js` but client side it call render function of `/programs/[program_id].js`  where `router.query.program_id` is `undefined`**

Not sure why this is happening? i was expecting it to call the render for `/programs/index.js`

###### /programs/index.js

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const programs = await fetchProgramsList(); //Fetch API
  return {
    props: {
      programs: programs.data,
    },
  };
}
```

###### /programs/[program_id].js

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { program_id: "P01" } },
      { params: { program_id: "P02" } },
      { params: { program_id: "P03" } },
    ],
    fallback: false,
  };
}
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const programData = await fetchProgramDetails(params.program_id); //Fetch API
  return {
    props: {
      programData: programData.data,
    },
  };
```

Comment: @juliomalves, code is bit large so updated entire code in `gist` , plz check this URL
[https://gist.github.com/nivendha/85f2857616012188a1aa7067d29dc62f](https://gist.github.com/nivendha/85f2857616012188a1aa7067d29dc62f)

Answer (score 0):

The option of only using `/programs/[program_id].js` is not valid because Dynamic Routes (including Catch-all routes) do not have an `undefined` state.
So try it as following:

```
/pages
|_/index.js
|_/programs.js
|_/programs
   |_/[program_id].js
```

Comment: The `/programs/index.js` file in OP's folder structure would handle routing to `/programs`.